# Login display error message

Tags: database, delphi, authentication, filter

I need my program to log a user in from a database. This entails a diver number (like a username) and a password which is already in the database. Unfortunately, I don't know SQL right now and would rather use a technique similar to the one I've done here. I get an error message in run time that says: adotblDiversInfo: Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset. Thank you so much for your help in advance (:
This is my code:

```
procedure TfrmHomeScreen.btnLogInClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iDiverNumber : Integer;
  sPassword, sKnownPassword : String;
  bFlagDiverNumber, bFlagPassword, Result : Boolean;
begin
  iDiverNumber := StrToInt(ledDiverNumber.Text);
  sPassword := ledPassword.Text;
  with frmDM do
    adotblDiversInfo.Filtered := False;
    frmDM.adotblDiversInfo.Filter := 'Diver Number' + IntToStr(iDiverNumber);
    frmDM.adotblDiversInfo.Filtered := True;
    if frmDM.adotblDiversInfo.RecordCount = 0 then
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(iDiverNumber) + ' cannot be found')
    else
      begin
        sKnownPassword := frmDM.adotblDiversInfo['Password'];
        if sKnownPassword = sPassword then
          ShowMessage('Login successful')
       else
          ShowMessage('Incorrect password. Please try again');
      end;
end;
```

Comment: Your problem isn't anything to do with SQL.  What the error message means is that you're attempting an operation on a dataset that's invalid until after you've opened it (the dataset).  You should mention in your q what line the error occurs on, so readers don't have to guess.  Btw avoid "with" like the plague.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't declare a variable named `Result`. Even though it's not a keyword, it serves a special purpose for functions. Declaring your own in procedures is looking to create confusion.

Comment: Also: are you using plain text passwords?!

Comment: Thank you all for the response (: I don't even know why I have the result there, Craig. The error occurred in run time not design time so I'm not entirely sure on how to mention which line, MartynA. And yes I am using plain text passwords, birger.

Comment: Ah, ok, it sounds like you haven't got the Debug Info compiler options turned on for your project, otherwise when the exception occurs, the IDE would take you to the exact line line in your project where is has.  How to turn them on varies a bit with Delphi version, so best to look up in the OLH.  Once you have, put a breakpoint on the first line of your click handler, then single step using F8 when the bp trips.

Comment: It was because I had to open it (: Rooky error xD But thank you for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you've forgotten to open the dataset before attempting to access it. Use `frmDM.adoTblDiversInfo.Open;` or `frmDM.adoTblDiversInfo.Active := True;` to do so before trying to use the table.

Your code could be much simpler (and faster) if you change it somewhat. Instead of filtering the entire dataset, simply see if you can `Locate` the proper record.

```
procedure TfrmHomeScreen.btnLogInClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  iDiverNumber : Integer;
begin
  if not frmDM.adoTblDiversInfo.Active then
    frmDM.adoTblDiversInfo.Open;

  iDiverNumber := StrToInt(ledDiverNumber.Text);
  sPassword := ledPassword.Text;
  if frmDM.adoTblDiversInfo.Locate('Diver Number', iDiverNumber, []) the
  begin
    if frmDM.adoTblDiversInfo['Password'] = ledPassword.Text then
      ShowMessage('Login successful')
    else
      ShowMessage('Invalid password. Please try again.');
  end
  else
    ShowMessage(ledDiverNumber.Text);
end;
```

Comment: @kelly:  I realise this was your first, but it's a good idea to get into the habit of accepting an helpful answer like Ken's obviously was, by clicking the Tick icon.  Accepting an answer increases your own rep as well as the answer's, so helps you towards clearing some of the restrictions SO imposes on what new users can do.